# How do I get this scroll effect?

Tags: jquery

I just started to learn jQuery and I came across this site- [TEDx Portland](http://tedxportland.com/) and I really like the scroll effect and the fact that the entire site is just one page.

Considering I'm a beginner are there any resources one can point at so that I accomplish a similar effect(the smooth and eased animation)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a jQuery plugin, for example [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 2):

No plugin necessary with jQuery:

```
$('.scrollPage').click(function() {
   var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
   var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
   $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-20}, 500 );
   return false;
});
```

The code gets the href from the anchor and uses it as the target element. If you want to adjust the scroll speed just change the 500. [Demo](http://examples.oncemade.com/2009/07/animated-page-scroll-with-jquery-example/). [Original](http://oncemade.com/animated-page-scroll-with-jquery/).

And here's [another tutorial](http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/).